# Unable to click “Allow” or “Block” in Permission popup in Chrome browser using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can’t click on “allow” in the permission pop up. I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
WebDriver driver= DriverFactory.getDriver();
Alert al= driver.switchTo().alert();
al.accept();
```

Does it exist any other option to handle the click of Chrome Browser pop ups.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me too
First create a java.awt.Robot instance,

Then call keyPress() method on robot

- Then do (VK_TAB) then (VK_ENTER)

(VK_TAB) is used to go to ‘Allow’ button, then (VK_ENTER) clicks it.